# Is it possible to add "Other calendar by URL" in google calendar API?

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-ruby-client, webcal, google-apis-explorer

I have been unable to find help on [Google Calendar APIreference](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/).  I am looking for a resource which makes the same things like option in user interface "Add by URL"( see below).

[image]

Is it possible to add other calendars by URL through Google Calendar API?

Comment: I have no idea if this will work I haven't actually tried and I don't have an alternate calendar type to try it with.    https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/insert   use your URL as the id.  Let us know if it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont think this is supported yet. You can read below the "Add by URL" that this is for iCals.

With respect to DalmTo's suggestion, I tried placing an iCal URL as "id" in the POST request in
[CalendarList.insert](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/insert#try-it). It didn't work.

I got an error saying:

```
"code": 404,
  "message": "Not Found"
```

But, when I added it manually using the Add by URL field, it was inserted.
This only means that `CalendarList.insert` doesn't accept iCal URLs. I also checked the [CalendarList resource](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList#resource) and no mention of iCal URLs were present.

Comment: I agree with you, I've tried to do like in suggestion above and it doesn't work. Also I've tried to do  -  in Calendars: insert in body add  { "summary": "MyCalendarURL.ics" }, but it also doesn't work. I've found this posts https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/google-calendar-help-dataapi/Add$20by$20URL|sort:relevance/google-calendar-help-dataapi/Xx7qpyicpx8/hzPT9lBNBn8J , so I think google developers  have strongly arguments  that they have not added this resource to API, since 2011.

Answer (score 0):

Add by URL is not very good functionality.
We tried that and there are 2 main reasons why not to use it:
1. Users won't use it. They just don't understand it as it is too complicated. I understand you are looking solution for that - fine and good luck;
2. Google doesn't like it. For MANY years already Google is keeping artiicial time-lag between your ical source and Google Calendar. Approximately 6 hours. Meaning - if you update event in your application the update will be visible in Google Calendar after around 2-6 hours.

Maybe, just maybe, if you find Server-toServer solution for this, it is fixed but adding ical link is a waste.